# Why does IIS get stuck on startup at PipelineRuntime.WaitForRequestsToDrain()?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

When I launch a .NET 4.5 web application from Visual Studio 2013 (but I am not entirely sure that it is limited to this scenario) IIS gets stuck while starting up the application. If I kill `w3wp.exe`, it restarts automatically and the application works fine.

When I attach the debugger to the hung `w3wp.exe` I get the stack trace below. There is just one managed thread called `Worker thread`, all other are running native code - as such there isn't any custom code running/sleeping at the moment - just this one.

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.WaitForRequestsToDrain()
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.Dispose()
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain(object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you deserve an answer. I ran into the same issue and it looks like I've resolved it.

For me it was occurring because I wasn't tagging my await commands with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. I believe that not using it causes the main thread to do all of the work, constantly staying busy by switching code segments. But this thread gets hung somewhere via a deadlock (a waits for b, b waits for c, c waits for a).

Adding `.ConfigAwait(false)` results in parallel processing with no context instead of linear processing within a single context.

Hope you got it fixed.